# Set Default Interpreter for .php files on Mac OS X / linux

Tags: php, linux, macos, command-line

On OS X and Linux I can run `.php` files from from the command line if two things are true:

1. I set the executable bit (`chmod +x file.php`)
2. I have added `#!/usr/bin/php` to the top of the file.

If I want to run a shell script, however, I noticed that I can **omit step 2**, and it will use a default interpreter, `/usr/bin/sh`

Is there a configuration options I can set, that basically says "if the file is executable (`chmod +x`) and the extension is `.php` then use `/usr/bin/php` as the interpreter?

My ideal solution would allow `file.php` to live in `/localhost/www/`, and allow it to be accessed via a web browser as `http://localhost/file.php` or in terminal via:

```
/localhost/www/$ ./file.php
```

Comment: What is the problem of adding that line at the top ?

Comment: Wen I run the script from a web browser the line shows up as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* there is some way to associate a MIME type other than by looking at the interpreter line or the extension, you could do it.  But I suspect what you're really asking is "magically recognize random PHP scripts that don't mark themselves as such", and the "magically" part means the answer is "no".  Humans can recognize it with sufficient reliability, but your computer can't without help.  Which is why there are file extensions and interpreter lines.  (In general it won't be smart enough to reliably distinguish PHP from Perl.)

If you *do* have an extension (`.php` from your subject line, as opposed to the `.sh` in the question itself), then `zsh` has some ability to configure that but `bash` doesn't as yet.  However, you can make `open` on OS X and `xdg-open` on Linux handle it correctly; the former is configured fro the Get Info dialog and the latter via `xdg-mime` or your desktop's MIME type database (the latter preferred as sometimes getting raw XDG settings imported is a black art).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to clarify the question, I realized I had a few typos in it. Does it make any better sense now as far as what I want to do with it? I'm not trying to rely on MIME types.

Comment: MIME types are the intermediary both with `open`/`xdg-open` and with Apache. You still want `open`/`xdg-open`. Or you can see if you can get `zsh` to pick based on an extension, but `bash` won't do it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if that's helpful or not. I would like to keep the files associated with TextMate as the default "open" action. And if I have to type something before the files at the command line, like `open`, I mine as well set up my own alias like run-php that would do something like `/usr/bin/php file.php`. Seems like as smart and powerful as linux and mac are they should be able to handle something like this.

Comment: Then you have to go with a different shell that lets you do the associations. `bash` won't.

Comment: I'm guessing your preference is zsh. Any suggestions for where to find documentation or what keywords I should google for?

Comment: Thats not the point so much as that so far `zsh` is the only shell that has broken with tradition and begun adding execute by extension. And even so it's a user extension, not part of the shell proper. See http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?(zsh)MIME%2520Functions for details.